# Java visitor pattern working with both primitive type and class

Tags: java

I'm working on trying to reduce the number of methods I need for one project, so instead of so many overloading, I wish to find a way to dynamically take actions according to the type/class of the input parameters.
I have parameters of both primitive type (long, double), and class (String, array, or self-defined classes).

I have this method that should be available to all of them - which is also overloaded.

```
public void write(long n){
    //Some operations
}

public void write(String str){
    //Some other operations
}
```

I tried using Java generic types, but it didn't work - such like this

```
public <T> void mainMethod(T... inputs){
    for (T input: inputs){
        write(input);
    }    
}
```

This would give me error Cannot resolve method 'write(T)'.
I think I can work with a bunch of instanceof and other casting operations, but I'm just wondering if there's any other ways?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to declare `Long` instead of `long`, the compiler should take care of unboxing automatically

Comment: It depends on the functionality of your method. For example if your `write` method just converts your object to a string and writes it into a file or something else you can simply choose `public void write( Object obj )` as your method signature and call `obj.toString()` because the actual called method does not depend on the declared type rather then the runtime type.

Comment: You mean from mainMethod or the write function? The later one is actually from another library so I don't think I should change the way it is..

Comment: Why do you need a bunch of instanceof when `T` can represent just *one type* at runtime

Comment: Reducing method count is a bad goal. Good code almost always consists of many small methods. Even if reducing method count were useful, merely adding dynamic dispatching - which is what you're asking about - wouldn't accomplish that. Otoh, reducing duplicated code by refactoring is a good goal. Eliminating branching based on object type is a good goal. Are you really trying to achieve one of these last two? Something else?

Comment: @Gene I feel that all the mainMethods look the same - one way or another, they are simply different in their input parameters and the write method that these different variables call, so I want to have a more generic method.

Comment: can you please describe how you do implement the 'visitor design pattern'? i don't see any of it yet....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all objects and types you have a different `write` for need different treatment, I can think of five ways.

Bad: Changing mainMethod to contain lots of `instanceof` checks. This doesn't bring down the overloaded method count of `write()`. Some IDEs will complain with a warning that this is 'not object oriented' enough.

Bad: Make `write()` accept `Object` and place the chain of `if`s there. Same IDE warning.

No: You could take the functionality of `write` out of the utility class and put it in the subclass of every object that you would otherwise pass to `write`. This is not possible because of primitives. You could extend Number but it's a lot of hassle.

No: You can, for each object `T input` reflectively obtain the correct method based on the parameter type and *invoke* that. Still doesn't answer your question of how to reduce the number of overloads.

Best: Try to find the common denominator of what you want to do with all those radically different parameters. In case of `write` it is probably either conversion to `String` or some form of serialization or conversion. In each of those cases you can do two things.

- 'Preprocess' the object (for example `String.valueOf()`, `.toString()` or your own method) to get one, or a small number of, types so you don't need as much methods. (Like what's done with `System.out.println`)
- Create an interface to all non-primitive classes that signify that your `write` function can accept with them (Like what's done with `Serializable`) This interface should expose some methods that `write` can use, to eliminate the need for a chain of `if`s.

---

As for why a chain of `instanceof` is bad, I quote IntelliJ's warning:

> Reports any chains of if-else statements all of whose conditions are
>   instanceof expressions or class equality expressions (e.g. comparison
>   with String.class). Such constructions usually indicate a failure of
>   object-oriented design, which dictates that such type-based dispatch
>   should be done via polymorphic method calls rather than explicit
>   chains of type tests.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still wondering about why making write() accept Object is not good..? Can I keep write(Object o) and the write methods for other self-defined classes?

Comment: I assumed all your objects need different treatment (answer updated). In a single method accepting `Object` you need a chain of `instanceof` which is bad practice. On the other hand, if all you need to do is `String.valueOf()` to any object you put in (and `Arrays.toString()` for arrays), then you don't need methods for self-defined classes.